# Mysql group replication can't add instance

Tags: mysql, mysql-group-replication

config file on 22.22.22.22:

```
...

loose-group_replication_group_name="aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
loose-group_replication_start_on_boot=off
loose-group_replication_local_address= "127.0.0.1:33061"
loose-group_replication_group_seeds= "127.0.0.1:33061,33.33.33.33:33061"
loose-group_replication_bootstrap_group=off
```

I made as docs say:

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
CREATE USER rpl_user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO rpl_user@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=1
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_USER='rpl_user', MASTER_PASSWORD='password' FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery';

INSTALL PLUGIN group_replication SONAME 'group_replication.so';

SET GLOBAL group_replication_bootstrap_group=ON;
START GROUP_REPLICATION;
SET GLOBAL group_replication_bootstrap_group=OFF;
```

Everything ok so far...

And I have a config file on 33.33.33.33:

```
...

loose-group_replication_group_name="aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
loose-group_replication_start_on_boot=off
loose-group_replication_local_address= "127.0.0.1:33061"
loose-group_replication_group_seeds= "22.22.22.22:33061,127.0.0.1:33061"
loose-group_replication_bootstrap_group=off
```

Also I follow docs:

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
CREATE USER rpl_user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO rpl_user@'%';
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=1;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_USER='rpl_user', MASTER_PASSWORD='password' FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery';

INSTALL PLUGIN group_replication SONAME 'group_replication.so';
```

Everything still OK..

But when I Enter

```
START GROUP_REPLICATION;
```

on 33.33.33.33 an error occurs:

ERROR 3092 (HY000): The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group. Please see more details on error log.

error.log:

```
2018-08-31T13:50:20.850316Z 14 [Warning] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Automatically adding IPv4 localhost address to the whitelist. It is mandatory that it is added.'
2018-08-31T13:50:20.850719Z 16 [System] [MY-010597] [Repl] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_applier' executed'. Previous state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2018-08-31T13:50:21.041909Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] read failed'
2018-08-31T13:50:21.056819Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 33061'
```

What to do?

MySQL version: 8.0.12

Answer (score 2):

You are biding the communication address to a localhost address:

> loose-group_replication_local_address= "127.0.0.1:33061"
>
> loose-group_replication_local_address= "127.0.0.1:33061"

But you are then trying to contact the members using public addresses.
If the member is to be contactable publicly it needs to bind to a public address.

Comment: Hello @Pedro - I'm also facing the same issue. If I bind with local then Group Replication works, but other servers cannot join the group. If I provide public IP then the group replication doesn't start. It fails with this error - `There is no local IP address matching the one configured for the local node` Any Idea what to do in this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to that? I'm also facing the same issue...